# Set the value and text of a select option from Javascript table

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a table variable

```
var stations = [
    [0,'JAMAA EL FNA','L1'],
    [1,'KOUTOUBIA','L1'],
    [2,'HOTEL DE VILLE','L1'],
...
```

How to set the values and text of a dropdown box from this table (second column)?

```
 <select id="select1" name="select1">
    <option value='test'>test<option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Can I know what you tried so far?

Comment: This is my first time using html and javascript, I followed some tutorials to write this, can't find how to solve this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code as follows;

```js
var stations = [
    [0,'JAMAA EL FNA','L1'],
    [1,'KOUTOUBIA','L1'],
    [2,'HOTEL DE VILLE','L1']];
    
    for(var i=0;i<stations.length;i++){
    var opText = "<option val='"+stations[i][0]+"'>"+stations[i][1]+"</option>";
      $("#selecObject").append(opText);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selecObject"></select>
```